# WIll replacing my iphone 12 battery with one from selfservicerepair.com cause the unknown part warning to appear?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, repair

WIll replacing my iphone 12 battery with one from selfservicerepair.com cause the unknown part warning to appear (if I replace it myself, the sites sais they are genuine and it is linked as the official store for Apple parts in Apple support)?

https://support.apple.com/self-service-repair

https://selfservicerepair.com/home

Comment: As far as I know, the phone has the chip that can be serialized to the logic board but it was only enabled in the iPhone 14 models. I don’t know for sure so you might need to verify. However, the battery will still work as expected.